# Apache Spark not able to start properly

Tags: apache-spark

First Situation:

I have downloaded spark on ubuntu 14. But when am running it below result is coming. Its not able to start properly and asking root user password.

```
root@sueeze-Lenovo-G580:~/Spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin# ./start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/sueeze/Spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ashish-Lenovo-G580.out
root@localhost's password:
```

May I know please:

1) What is this ?

2) Why its happening ?

3) Why its asking root's password ?

Situation 2:

I have fixed situation one by adding localhost to in slave file.

Now both master and worker is running. I want to know what was missed but when I add localhost it started running ?
But it still asks me root's password when it starts worker node. I mean first it starts Master but when the moment it goes to worker to start it asks for root's password. Why ? And how can I fix that...?

I'm running spark only on my local machine so master and slave for both my local machine is available. Correct...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The launch scripts for the standalone cluster use SSH connections to log onto worker machines (whether that's on localhost or not).

That is why the script is prompting you for the password.

You need to configure password-less login on those machines using SSH keys to prevent the interactive prompts. In short, this is about allowing the command `ssh localhost` or `ssh workermachinehost` to normally go without prompting your for the password (use `ssh-copy-id`)

You should be able to use a non-root user, as long as you've created the user with the same name on both master and worker machines.

Check [this documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) for information on running a standalone cluster.